# qrcode generator using python for windows

Tags: python, qr-code

I am looking for qrcode generator for python window version. Can anyone help me to find out.

I didn't get anywhere.

Please help me.

Thanks,
manu

Answer (score 4):

either you have to

1. Compile it yourself; or
2. if you only need to generate the codes (i.e. encoding but no decoding), use [pyqrencode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqrencode/0.2) that you can get from PyPi (e.g. `pip install pyqrencode`)

If you don't have [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), I suggest you start by installing [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads) and then use `easy_install` to install pip (of course, you can cut corners by just doing an `easy_install pyqrencode`

Answer (score 4):

Try `pyqrnative` it's a Python port of an existing Javascript library to generate QR Codes.

http://code.google.com/p/pyqrnative/

- Christian

Answer (score 1):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/qrcode

Answer (score 0):

The self-proclaimed hackish [pyqrcode](http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/) seems to do both decode and encode. The encode is in C++ and the Decode is in Java. Python glues them together.

Answer (score 0):

pyqrnative is working pretty well for me. I wish I could find some documentation in English for it. Would like to know the relationship between data content size and the first "typeNumber" argument.