# Generate circular qr-code like a messenger or a kik code using Python

Tags: python, qr-code

Can I generate a QR-code in circular shape using Python, like the ones Facebook Messenger or kik use? I have visited many sites but I cannot find that type of QR-code. By default, Python generates square-shaped QR-codes, but in my project I want a round QR-code. Is it possible to create a round QR-code?

An example is in the image below.

[image: Round QR code from some Messenger profile]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [qrcode generator using python for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888125/qrcode-generator-using-python-for-windows)

Comment: @AnshumanTiwari Tiwari yes i am used  pyqrencode but it display in square shape Qr-code but i want to generate in  circular shape. is that possible that?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://github.com/jveres/qrcode-bot

Comment: @AnshumanTiwari Tiwari Thanks. might be its usedfull to me.

Comment: @AnshumanTiwari bro, i tried but it can not work for me

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904227/how-can-i-generate-a-circular-qr-code-like-a-messenger-or-a-kik-code